# Recursively create folders using JSON file

Tags: java, json, recursion

I have two json files.

all_packages.json

```
{
  "backbone": ["jQuery", "underscore"],
  "jQuery": ["queryJ"],
  "underscore": ["lodash"],
  "queryJ": [],
  "lodash": []
}
```

dependencies.json

```
{
  "projectName": "Test0000",
  "dependencies": ["backbone"]
}
```

I am trying to implement a simple command-line tool that reads dependencies.json file and outputs what else should be installed in order for everything to work.

There can be already installed packages, which are going to be located in a folder, called installed_modules, where each dependency is a separate folder, which name is the name of the package.
The tool should read the dependencies.json and all_packages.json and output that the following libraries are going to be installed:

Example:

```
Installing backbone.
In order to install backbone, we need jQuery and underscore.
Installing jQuery.
In order to install jQuery, we need queryJ.
Installing queryJ.
Installing underscore.
In order to install underscore, we need lodash. Lodash is already installed.
All done.
```

After the program end the folder structure should be like this.

```
installed_modules/
├── backbone
├── jQuery
├── lodash
├── queryJ
└── underscore
```

I`m trying to make all this with recursion with no hard coded values but with no luck.

---

**EDIT**

@William Morrison

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(".../dependencyResolving/dependencies.json"));
            JSONObject dependencies = (JSONObject) obj;

            Object obj1 = parser.parse(new FileReader("../dependencyResolving/all_packages.json"));
            JSONObject allPacks = (JSONObject) obj1;

            JSONArray deps = (JSONArray) dependencies.get("dependencies");
            Iterator<String> iterator = deps.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("Installing " + iterator.next() + ".");
            }

            //Here i do not know how to check in all_packages which are                                   
            //dependencies and i can not create the folders.
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Comment: Begin by building a graph data structure from the full json structure.  Have items with no dependencies represented as leaves in this graph.  After the graph is built, process each item, walking the dependency graph, depth-first, to leaves, then install each item as the recursion unwinds.

Comment: @Gaël I can not make good recursive call. I make some folder creation using hard coded values but it is not a good way and thats why i asked here.

Comment: Can you post what you've attempted so far?

Comment: @William Morrison I will post some code as an answer.

Comment: Someone will help me guys ? I can not solve the problem for quite some time now :(